# Disable item from combobox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

VB.net/Windows Form

I have a combobox with items like this:

Index  Text

0     --Brand--

1     Honda

2     Nissan

3     Ford

4     --Model--

5     Civic

6     Altima

7     Explorer

But i want that the use is not allowed to select the item 0 and 4 (Brand,Model), does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this or maybe i'm not using the right control, or maybe i need to use a specific event.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: In the selected event, test the text?  There is not a built in way to literally disable items, but if you want to get into the OwnderDraw approach, you could build an Item class that has an enabled property which you draw accordingly.

Comment: like Plutonix said, check the text. If it starts with --- then set your index back to -1 (nothing selected).